# Seaborn Boxplot with Same Color for All Boxes

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, boxplot

I am using seaborn and want to generate a box plot where all boxes have the same color.  For some reason seaborn uses different colors for each box and doesn't have an option to stop this behavior and set the same color for all boxes.

How can I force seaborn to use the same color for all boxes?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 20))
sns.boxplot(y='categorical_var', x='numeric_var', ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `color` parameter:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, color="seagreen")
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you can use `color='C0'` in order to avoid hard-coding a specific color. This will instead get the first color from Matplotlib's (customizable) color cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own palette and set the color of boxes like:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

sns.set_color_codes()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
pal = {day: "b" for day in tips.day.unique()}
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, palette=pal)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Another way is to iterate over artists of boxplot and set the color with `set_facecolor` for every artist of axis istance:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
for box in ax.artists:
    box.set_facecolor("green")
```

[image]

Comment: The data is somewhat large.  Is there any way to do this without running a pass of the data?

Comment: these loops are complete unnecessary for a single color.